# How do you conditionally order by multiple fields in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

My specific use case is that I want to sort a list of users by name; first name, last name. The user has a preferred name and a legal name. I want to order by the preferred name if it is present, but the legal name as fall back.

For example, given the follow table:

```
 id | first_name | last_name | preferred_first_name | preferred_last_name
----+------------+-----------+----------------------+---------------------
  9 | Ryan       | Bently    | Alan                 |
 10 | Ryan       | Do        | Billy                | Baxter
 11 | Olga       | Clancierz |                      |
 12 | Anurag     | Plaxty    |                      | Henderson
 13 | Sander     | Cliff     | Billy                |
```

I want to sort like this:

```
Alan Bently
Anurag Henderson
Billy Baxter
Billy Cliff
Olga Clancierz
```

Normally, with just one name set of name fields I would just do this:

```
SELECT * from users ORDER BY users.first_name, users.last_name
```

What is the best way to order by preferred name fields when present, but fall back to other name fields when they are not present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`ORDER BY COALESCE(users.preferred_first_name,users.first_name), users.last_name`

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem!  Just remember to accept the answer/close the question.

Comment: Yeah, don't worry. There is a minimum time limit though.

Comment: Ah didn't know that; only ever had one question answered properly!